# Chrome Console get values from xpath array

Tags: html, google-chrome, xpath, google-chrome-devtools

I'm using the Google Chrome Console to get an array of all the elements that have a class of `attrValue`. This is what I'm using:

```
$x('//*[@class="attrValue"]');
```

And this is my output:

```
<td class="attrValue">Transway 1A</td>, <td class="attrValue">Northbound/Westbound</td>, <td class="attrValue">Facing West</td>
```

It works great to get an array of all the elements but I am trying to get an array of the values within those elements. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Get the `text()`:

```
$x('//*[@class="attrValue"]/text()');
```

Comment: Awesome! Now within the array of elements, I also have a couple of nested elements like this `<td class="attrValue"><span class="esriNumericValue">110004</span></td>`. How could I include that value into the array? Thanks.

Comment: @user1819087 If all of the elements in the array have that `span` inside, it is just `//*[@class="attrValue"]/span/text()`.

Comment: @user1819087 `//*[@class="attrValue"]//text()` could also be applied in your case.

Comment: Only a few of them have the `span` inside.